# Como retornar uma valor de uma coluna checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-datatables

Estou tentando pega o ID da linha selecionada com :checked porém não estou conseguindo.

### HTML

```
<table id="dividas">
    <thead class="thead-inverse">
        <tr>
             <th>#</th>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Nome</th>
            <th>Fone</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
                <td>01</td>
                <td>Pedro</td>
                <td>+55 82 866 869 869</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
                <td>02</td>
                <td>Carlos</td>
                <td>+55 82 866 869 869</td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
</table>
```

### SCRIPT

```
$('#save').click(function () {
            $('#dividas').find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function () {

                //retornar valor de uma coluna
          });

       });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer algo assim:

```js
const $inputs = $('#table-data td input');
const $button = $('#save');

$button.on('click', () => {
  const ids = [];
  
  $inputs.each(function() {
    const $input = $(this);
    
    // Adicione o ID à lista caso o input estiver marcado:
    if ($input.prop('checked')) {
      const id = $input.parent().next().text();
      ids.push(id);
    }
  });
  
  // Faça o que quiser com os IDs.
  console.log(ids);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table
  id="table-data"
  class="table table-striped table-inverse table-responsive"
>
  <thead class="thead-inverse">
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Nome</th>
      <th>Fone</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td>01</td>
      <td>Pedro</td>
      <td>+55 82 866 869 869</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td>02</td>
      <td>Carlos</td>
      <td>+55 82 866 869 869</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button id="save">Salvar</button>
```

---

É bom ressaltar que com o JavaScript moderno, podemos fazer muitas coisas (tudo, na verdade) com mais facilidade que o jQuery.

Veja como o código acima ficaria com um paradigma um pouco mais declarativo e sem usar jQuery:

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('#table-data td input');
const button = document.querySelector('#save');

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const ids = [...inputs]
    .filter((input) => input.checked)
    .map((input) => input.parentElement.nextElementSibling.textContent);

  console.log(ids);
});
```

```html
<table id="table-data">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Nome</th>
      <th>Fone</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td>01</td>
      <td>Pedro</td>
      <td>+55 82 866 869 869</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td>02</td>
      <td>Carlos</td>
      <td>+55 82 866 869 869</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button id="save">Salvar</button>
```

Comment: Muito bom esse código, mas a ideia é pegar todos os IDs das linhas selecionadas para eu mandar para uma REQUEST e executar uma QUERY.

Comment: Ah, beleza! Entendi errado a pergunta, perdão... :v Vou editar a resposta...

Comment: Luiz, o seu código sumiu. Fiz um teste com um código postado e deu certo aqui, mas não está mais postado.

Comment: Isso, mesmo. Muito obrigado

Answer (score 1):

**Tente este código:**

```js
let inputsCheck = [];

$("button").click(function() {

  inputsCheck = [];

  $("input[type='checkbox']").each(function(ev, elemt) {
  
 if (elemt.checked) {
  //Se quiser pegar somente o ID e jogar no inputsCheck array, então
  //faça assim: elemt.id no lugar de elemt, abaixo:
  inputsCheck.push(elemt);
  
   }
 });

  //Elementos marcados
  console.log(inputsCheck);
});
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <table id="dividas">
        <thead class="thead-inverse">
            <tr>
                 <th>#</th>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Nome</th>
                <th>Fone</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" id="id_1"></td>
                    <td>01</td>
                    <td>Pedro</td>
                    <td>+55 82 866 869 869</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" id="id_2"></td>
                    <td>02</td>
                    <td>Carlos</td>
                    <td>+55 82 866 869 869</td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>
    </table>
    <button>Salvar</button>
```